# why don't I see a date selector with firefox?

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, datepicker

The following *HTML* generates a *date selector* on chrome :

```
<html>
<head> <title> </title> </head>
<body>
    <form>
      <input type="date" />
    </form>
</body>
```

[image]

but it shows a simple text-field on `firefox 19.0.2`. Why is that ? Is it that firefox doesn't support all the featurs of `HTML 5` ?

Comment: You basically need to check what features supported or not http://html5test.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is that ? Is it that firefox doesn't support all the featurs of HTML 5 ?

Yes, FireFox doesn't support all HTML 5 features. For example FireFox 19 doesn't support the `date` field.

Here's more details about browser support the `date` input field: http://caniuse.com/input-datetime

Comment: any reason why it doesn't support the _date_ feature ?

Comment: No particular reason. HTML5 is still a draft, so I wouldn't expect mass browser support until the specification gets final. You cannot possibly expect browsers implementing something that is not yet defined, right? Once the specification is finished and HTML5 becomes an industry standard you can expect support from all browsers.

Comment: yeah but since _chrome_ implemented the feature I thought about firefox.

Comment: One advice I can give you if you decide to use some HTML5 feature is to always check the http://caniuse.com site for browser support and if you need to use it in all browsers, even those that do not support it, provide some fallback (probably javascript oriented) alternative to your users.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: "I wouldn't expect mass browser support until the specification gets final" ... so you mean we need to wait for at least 2016?  I love working at the speed of W3C (sarcasm of coarse)!!

Comment: @Jeach, no I didn't mean that you should wait until 2016 to get final specification. You could always have a downgrade javascript version for browsers that do not yet support the HTML5 features that you want to use.

Comment: It's September 2015 and still no date type in Firefox. The 2016 joke is getting less and less funny....